# Usar método onclick cambiar página

Tags: javascript, html, aplicación-web, onclick

estoy haciendo una aplicación web, y tengo un boton que tiene que enviarte a la página anterior, he conseguido que la palabra "Atras" del boton al clicar en el me lleve a la otra pagina, pero el propio boton como tal no funciona. Estoy usando el método onclick pero si teneis otra alternativa no importa, gracias. He puesto una parte del código de la página, y el boton a ver es "Atras".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
 crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Vapers de LGS</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript" lang="JavaScript">

function paraAtras() {
 document.getElementById("boton").href="inicio.html";
}

</script>

<!-- Algunos de los estilos de la página de vapers entre ellos el fondo, los textos, colores, fotos... -->

<style>

body {
 background-image:
  url("https://d1di2lzuh97fh2.cloudfront.net/files/2f/2fq/200/2fqq8a.png?ph=6fd8d12f56");
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 color: green;
 font-size: 55px;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
}

</style>

<!-- Aquí va la estructura de la visualización de las fotos de los vapers con sus respectivos nombres y precios -->

<body>
 
 <div type="button" name="boton" id="boton" class="btn purple waves-effect back" align="center" onclick="paraAtras()"><a href="inicio.html" style="color: white;">Atrás</a></div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema es que estás tratando de definir un atributo `href` para un elemento que no lo admite. ¿Por qué no usas una etiqueta `<a>` que si que lo admite?

Comment: Es lo que use, pero no funcionaba, por lo que probé a hacer una funcion que me llevara a la otra página.

Comment: Si no te funcionaba una etiqueta `<a>` cuya función por la que fue creada es para definir hipervínculos es que seguramente tuvieses algo mal en la ruta de la página que querías abrir. Usar Javascript para imitar el comportamiento de una etiqueta HTML es un poco trabajar en balde.

Comment: Eso que has hecho ahí no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. No tienes un botón sino un `div` con un enlace dentro que funciona perfectamente. Puedes hacer con estilos que un enlace parezca un botón ya que usar una función que simule un enlace es complicarse la vida sin necesidad pudiendo usar un enlace normal y corriente, que como dice @phpMyGuel es para lo que se creo la etiqueta `<a>`

Comment: Ya se q tengo un div, probé el enlace y efectivamente funcionaba, pero quería que el "botón" como tal funcionase, no solo el texto que hubiera dentro, pq no se como hacer que la "caja" del botón funcionase con el  enlace también de la etiqueta <a>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de capturar el onclick en un Div, quítalo y deja que la etiqueta  te lleve a la dirección de su href que es su función.

Otra opción es modificar tu js function por esto

```
function paraAtras() {
         document.location.href = "inicio.html"
}
```

Comment: Justo eso, ya había visto el location pero no me funcionaba, tendría mal el código. Muchas gracias.